# Wiremock request does not match multipart

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm using Sprint boot 2.x and spring cloud contract verifier.
Right now I have problem with getting test succeed on a my contract.

I can't get contract working as wiremock does not accept my request for multipart call.

Hier is my example:

---

**CONTROLLER**:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import", headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"}, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public ResponseEntity importXbrl(@RequestPart("xml") MultipartFile xml) throws IOException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new SomeResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

 }
```

**CONTRACT:**

```
request: 
    method: "POST" 
    url: "/14/import" 
    multipart: 
      named: 
        - paramName: "xml" 
        fileName: 'xml' 
        fileContent: "file content" 
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream' 
    matchers: 
      headers: 
        - key: 'Content-Type' 
          regex: 'multipart/form-data;' 
      multipart: 
        named: 
          - paramName: xml 
            fileName: 
          predefined: non_empty 
        fileContent: 
          predefined: non_empty 
        contentType: 
          predefined: non_empty 
response: 
    status: 200 
    matchers: 
      headers: 
        - key: 'Content-Type' 
            regex: 'application/json.*'
```

**TEST:**

```
@Test public void test() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile xml = new MockMultipartFile("xml", "xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xml"));

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(REQUEST_URI)
            .file(xml)
            .andExpect(status().is(200));

}
```

**WIREMOCK**

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
POST                                                       | POST
/14/import                                                 | /14/import
                                                           |
                 <<<<< Body does not match
  "cursor" : 12                                            | Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"
}                                                          | Content-Type: application/octet-stream
                                                           | Content-Length: 0
                                                           | 
                                                           | 
                                                           | --0ZaonQTGe0xcK6YOS2D8T0R28KIFML7M--
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: Please format the post cause I can't read anything out of it. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. You haven't provided your setup, no information about versioning, nothing useful really.